# PyQt, set specific number of Line Edit inputs

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

I would like to set number of inputs (input = line edit) in one step and after click on the button I want to get the number of line edits. (As is shown in picture.)

[image]

For example, I have 3 input parameters, so I want to set the number 3, click on button and get 3 fields (line edits) for the inputs.

I don't want to create new widget for every option and replace the old one. (I have 4 parameters with variable value of inputs, too many combinations.)
Eventually I could insert multiple values into one into line edit but neither of these options sounds good to me. Do you have any tips?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: mmm, show what you tried

Comment: Qt-Designer is not going to work here. You'll have to do it in code at run time. Probably you'll want some kind of container widget (QGroupBox, QWidget, QStackedWidget, etc) in Designer with sensible minimumSize values for width and height. Then in your code, create a QVBoxLayout for your container and fill it with QLineEdit widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300,300)
        self.items = []
        self.item_count = 0

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("NUMBER OF LINE EDITS")

        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinBox.setRange(0, 7)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.set_item_count)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("apply", clicked=self.on_clicked)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit

        groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Line Edit")
        self.item_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(groupBox)
        self.item_layout.addStretch(2)

        g_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        g_layout.addWidget(label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(button, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        g_layout.addWidget(groupBox, 2, 0, 5, 3)

    def on_clicked(self):
        print( *[ item.text() for item in  self.items[:self.spinBox.value()] ], sep="\n" )

    def set_item_count(self, new_count:int):
        n_items = len(self.items)
        for ii in range(n_items, new_count):
            item = self.lineEdit(self)
            self.items.append(item)
            self.item_layout.insertWidget(n_items, item)
        for ii in range(self.item_count, new_count):
            self.item_layout.itemAt(ii).widget().show()
        for ii in range(new_count, self.item_count):
            self.item_layout.itemAt(ii).widget().hide()
        self.item_count = new_count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Widget()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! That's absolutelly perfect! Thank you so much.